# DES encryption in Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, des

I need to create a class that will encrypt the text and sends that to PHP server. Then PHP server Decode that.

*But problem is that, I don't know PHP so I can not write code with same logic (as I used in Java) to decrypt the text, so I am fully dependent on codes those are at Internet, but I am unable to find those code with same logic(Same in Java and PHP). I need only DES encryption.*

Can you provide me some links or codes, please?

Comment: I hope this is no real world application, if you want to use DES.

Comment: No, this is not a real world application.

Comment: Oh great, than you don't need real world answers! Cool.

Comment: Hello, could you help me with your file? Thanks! http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89757/data-encryption-standard-des-with-jpvm-java-pvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mcrypt-extension is what you want to use. You will find plenty of examples in the [documentatin](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) and the comments.

Comment: The last time I used the mcrypt extension directly (when building my own abstraction on top) it generated C strings (i.e. null terminated) rather than PHP strings (which can contain \0) - this may have been fixed in more recent versions - but worth bearing in mind.

Comment: will if this is all then you might just trim the string to get rid of the NUL-byte. (http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)